# Decode/Encode in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to decode this

```
BQtvZB9sm416x/DYBrf1FCWrnbejnX6ZWkh3uWQzt5k=
```

This text as "I am using stack overflow" in SQL server 2012. SQL Server will be given this as input

```
BQtvZB9sm416x/DYBrf1FCWrnbejnX6ZWkh3uWQzt5k=
```

and need to convert into

```
I am using stack overflow
```

in SQL Server.

Key: testing, algorithm: Tripledes, mode:CBC, encode output using: Base64

If you want check you can check over here: https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/

Thanks in advance

Comment: You tagged three specific versions of SQL Server, but only mentioned one. What _specific_ problem have you encountered? "I want" is a bit vague.

Comment: hi @HABO, on basis of link given above i just need to convert "BQtvZB9sm416x/DYBrf1FCWrnbejnX6ZWkh3uWQzt5k=" as "i am using stack overflow" in sql server 2012. means if you visit that website it's using some algos and key to convert in this encrypted string. Is it possible if sql server is given same encrypted string using same algo and key we are able to decrypt as "i am using stack overflow" as output in SELECT Query .My input to SELECT Query will be that encrypted string .it's ok if code not supported by lower version as we have upgraded to 2012.Just added more tags to get answer quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You're working with 2 subjects here, namely encoding and encrypting.

If you could explain what you want to accomplish we'd better be able to suggest something.

IF you want to encrypt and decrypt something entirely in the SQL server the you could use the encryptByPassPhrase/DecryptByPassPhrase functions. Its pretty easy to use.

Now encoding and decoding in TSQL can be done like this:

```
set @encoded = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@source"))', 'varchar(max)')
set @decoded = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@encoded"))', 'varbinary(max)')
```

Comment: hi henrik clausen,
Client will send encrypted string we just need to decrypt that code in SQL server 2012.